# Given a tridiagonal Matrix $K_n \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ with specific elements, show that det$(K_n) = n+1$

Tags: linear-algebra, induction, determinant, laplace-expansion, tridiagonal-matrices

Let $K_n \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, specifically for general $n \in \mathbb{N}$
$$
(K_n)_{ij} = 
\begin{cases}
2&,   i=j\\
-1&, \|i-j\| = 1\\
0 &, \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
where $1 \leq i,j \leq n$. For example for $n=3$ this results in
$$
K_3 = \begin {pmatrix}
 2 & -1 & 0 \\
-1 & 2 & -1 \\
0 & -1 & 2
\end {pmatrix}.
$$
Prove that det$(K_n) = n+1$.

My first approach is to use a proof by induction.
By calculating the determinant for the first five matrices using laplace's formula I found that for $n \geq 4$ the determinant seems to satisfy
$$
\text{det}(K_n) = 2 \text{det}(K_{n-1}) - \text{det}(K_{n-2}).
$$

Now it has been quite a while since i last used induction and I am having trouble forumlating the induction step. Naively i would argue that for $n+1$ we get
$$
\text{det}(K_{n+1}) = 2 \text{det}(K_n) - \text{det}(K_{n-1}) =2 (n+1) - n = n+2
$$
which I think concludes the proof, but I'm unsure, since I used the recursive determinant formula for $n+1$ as well as my induction hypothesis. Would i need to proof the determinant formula seperately? If so, how would one go about it?

Comment: I think your approach is perfectly fine. You'd use the induction "of the second kind" (that's how my prof called it) where you assume in the induction hypotheses that it is valid for all $n\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$ and then tackle $n+1$. BTW, don't forget your starting value, i.e. $n=1$. Trivial here.

Comment: No, you have to show that the recursive determinant formula is consistent with the definition of $K_n$, you have to prove that identity first.